# How to add next button into detail page jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am trying to add "next" button in detail page to go next detail page. I'm new in jqm. Is it possible to do that? Is there any way to load next page's detail?
Request json data at every page load may be solution, but it is not a good way.

Any solution will be helpful.

Thanks.
Here is the html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Movie List
        </h3>
    </div>        
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
            <ul data-role="listview"  id="movie-list" data-theme="a">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer">
        <h1>Copyright 2013</h1>
    </div>              
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="headline">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>                        
        <h3>
            Movie Info
        </h3>
    </div>        
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview"  id="movie-data" data-theme="a">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){      
    $('#movie-data').empty();
    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.id == movieInfo.id) {

            $('#movie-data').append('<li><img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"></li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Title: '+row.original_title+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Release date'+row.release_date+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.popularity+'</li>');   
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.vote_average+'</li>');             
            $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');            
        }
    });    
});

$(document).on('vclick', '#movie-list li a', function(){  
    movieInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });

});


var movieInfo = {
    id : null,
    result : null
}

var ajax = {  
    parseJSONP:function(result){  
        movieInfo.result = result.results;
        $.each(result.results, function(i, row) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row));

            $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"/><h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>' + row.vote_average + '/10</p></a></li>');
        });
        $('#movie-list').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8uac7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: demo now includes same page slide transition.

Here is your updated fiddle with a next button in the detail page:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8uac7/354/**

I added a variable to keep the current page index:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
```

Then in your pagebeforeshow I set the currentindex to the array index:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){      
    $('#movie-data').empty();
    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.id == movieInfo.id) {
            currentIndex = i;
            BindHeadline(row);
        }
    });    
});
```

Then on the click of the Next button, I simply check if the index is less than the array length, and if  so, increment it and rebind the form to the next movie:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnNext', function(){  
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex < movieInfo.result.length){
        var row = movieInfo.result[currentIndex]
        movieInfo.id = row.id;
        BindHeadline(row);
        $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", allowSamePageTransition: true } );           
    }
});

function BindHeadline(row){   
    $('#movie-data').empty();
    $('#movie-data').append('<li><img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"></li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Title: '+row.original_title+'</li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Release date'+row.release_date+'</li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.popularity+'</li>');   
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.vote_average+'</li>');             
    $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');              
}
```

You can of course implement a Previous button and also enable/disable the buttons when you reach the beginning/end of the array.

Comment: One more question, how can i integrate slide effect when i press the next button? Because it is always in one page. I can not use changepage event.

Comment: You can actually transition to the same page : $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", allowSamePageTransition: true } ); here is the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8uac7/354/

Comment: I have updated the main answer with the same page transition.